# Testing strings for keywords in java using AND, OR, and NOTS efficiently

Tags: java

I have a program that is running in an online game that answers questions as a help bot. It reads each message and checks that it contains certain keywords and if it does, the question is answered. I'm using && || and ! operators and a large nested/branched if else statements to do this, but I need something that is more efficient so it doesn't cause any lag. There is 140 contains processes in the program at the moment but the maximum that would be run at once is probably 70. The words that are searched for are on average about 5-6 characters long. The input msg is no more than 70 chars long.

```
if (msg.contains("where"))
{
    if (msg.contains("x1") && msg.contains("x2"))
    else if (msg.contains("x3") || msg.contains("x4"))
    else if (msg.contains("x5") && !msg.contains("x6"))
    else if (msg.contains("x7") && (msg.contains("x8") || msg.contains("x9"))
}
```

Comment: The time it takes to check if a small message contains 10 substrings will never cause any lag, especially compared to the time it takes to send a request and receive a response over the network. We're talking about going to your kitchen vs. going to the moon here. You're worried about the wrong thing.

Comment: @JBNizet You're absolutely right

Comment: There is over 200 lines of this, still no difference though?

Comment: I doubt it causes any significant performance problem. But I'm more worried about readability and maintainability. Without knowing exactly what you want to achieve, it's hard to give advice. But if you're looking for *words*, then you probably should splitthe messages in words first and store them in a Set, then search for the words in the set. That would make it more correct, and also faster.

Comment: Alright that sounds promising, basically whenever somebody writes a message in game the help bot tries to respond to them with a pre-stored answer, they might ask "where are green dragons" they key words would be  "wher", "green", and "drag", in this case if it contains all of the words it will send them back an answer. Can you give me some of the process names for the splitting of messages and set operations? or where should i look for them